# How to find table cell value that is clicked from ASP.NET MVC Page?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to find the find the Text of the Table cell (from TD) that is CLicked.

Basically, my JQuery Code is not htting this line.

**$("#myTable tbody tr").find("td:eq(" + i + ")").click(function() {**

My table has 88 Records when i tried $("#myTable tbody tr").length

But it is not find "td:eq(".

Appreciate all responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#myTable tbody tr td").click(function(){
  var clickedCell = $(this);
  alert(clickedCell.text());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean $("#myTable tbody tr td").eq(i).click(function() { ? And $("#myTable td") is enough I think.